# Recall api when language changed VueJs

Tags: vue.js, internationalization

I'm using i18n in my application, I have a navbar that contain a switcher to change the local language and saving it to local storage (the Lang variable for i18n locale and the langID for the apis calls):

```
<template>
  <v-select
    v-model="selected"
    :items="locales"
    style="max-width: 150px; margin-bottom:-15px"
    class="custom"
    item-value="code"
    @change="setLocale()"
  >
  </v-select>

</template>

<script>
  import { getSupportedLocales } from '@/i18n/supported-locales'
  export default {
    data () {
      return {
        locales: getSupportedLocales(),
        selected: {
          name: 'French',
          image: 'French.jpg',
          code: 'fr',
        },
        items: [
          {
            name: 'French',
            image: 'French.jpg',
            code: 'fr',
          },
          {
            name: 'English',
            image: 'English.jpg',
            code: 'en',
          }],
      }
    },
    mounted () {
      if (localStorage.Lang !== null) this.$i18n.locale = localStorage.Lang
      if (localStorage.Lang === 'fr') {
        this.selected = this.items[0]
      } else {
        this.selected = this.items[1]
      }
    },
    methods: {
      setLocale () {
        this.$i18n.locale = this.selected
        localStorage.Lang = this.$i18n.locale
        if (this.selected === 'fr') { localStorage.langID = 6 } else {
          localStorage.langID = 4
        }
      },
    },
  }
</script>
```

For now I added :

```
const lang = localStorage.langID ? localStorage.langID : 6
```

to my api Service to add in every request 
The problem is that i want whenever i change the language in navbar, the components should recall api with the new langID

Comment: the simplest way is to post a message to your API call control in your `setLocale` method.

Comment: The setLocale function is in the navbar component and the api calls are in another components

Comment: then you will need eventbus or vuex